# Angular Toggling Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap themed angular app that has 2 radio buttons that bring up separate pages. Both can't be selected at the same time. When one is selected I want the `btn btn-primary active` to be the class values while the other one which is not selected has the class attributes `btn btn-secondary`.

I've spent hours google searching and playing around with different things and nothing has worked. [Here's the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gs0s1FeIu3B2DsEMBkzp?p=preview) with my attempt so far. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your plunker demo didn't use `bootstrap` to use class `btn btn-primary btn-secondary` so add `bootstrap` link.

and invalid expression for `ng -class`. should use

`class="btn" ng-class="button.view1Selected ? 'btn-primary active' : 'btn-secondary'"`

insted of

`class="btn ng-class:button.view1Selected ? 'btn-primary active' : 'btn-secondary'"`

Better to use an array to store all view buttons info with selected property that initially false.

like: 
`$scope.views = [{isSelected: false},{isSelected: false}];`// index based 0 for 1st button ...` or can be specific property based as you need

and when clicked on any button then set that button is selected and set class according to your condition.Call a function to set specific button active flag.

like: `ng-click="selectedButton(1)"`

and check to set class like: `ng-class="views[0].isSelected ? 'btn-primary active' : 'btn-secondary'"`

`selectedButton` function like:

```
$scope.selectedButton = function(viewIndex){
    angular.forEach($scope.views, function(view, index) {
      if(viewIndex == index) {
        view.isSelected = ! view.isSelected;
      } else {
        view.isSelected = false;
      }
    });
  };
```

[See Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaq4z5psB8Yfm4jUvPvM?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

A few things that are off-

1. *You didn't include AngularJS*. Of course it won't run, it's not there at all...
2. You're trying to use ng-class as a class the wrong way. Aside from the fact that using the `ng-class` *attribute* is generally easier*, you have it formatted wrong. You have `ng-class=!view.isSelected ? 'btn-primary active' : 'btn-secondary'`, which should be `ng-class:!view.isSelected ? 'btn-primary active' : 'btn-secondary'`. Note the `:` instead of the `=` sign.

   *This is not to say that you *can't* use the `class` version of `ng-class` (it's definitely valid to do so), but I'd generally make the distinction to have static classes in the `class` attribute, and anything dynamic in `ng-class`.
3. You have no controller. While technically you can cause the view to "truthily" create a scope variable by negating undefined (which is a very sloppy way of doing it), this will at best allow you to have one binary/toggle radio set, or a set of mutually allowed toggles. You should have, *in your controller*, a scope variable that holds which button is pressed (each button setting it on click to something to indicate it's now them), and having `ng-class` evaluate for that.

Comment: I have updated [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gs0s1FeIu3B2DsEMBkzp?p=preview) based on your suggestions but still no luck

Comment: Your code still relies on something in scope called "`view`", which is undefined. While You can add a property to something casually, like adding things to scope, you can't add a property _to something that doesn't exist_ (i.e. scope exists, so you can add stuff to it, but `$scope.view` doesn't, so you can't add `$scope.view.isSelected`). In your controller, create `$scope.view` as an object. ... This still doesn't address the second part of point 3, though, in that even if you have `$scope.view.isSelected`, it's still one binary state.

Comment: im trying to avoid using `$scope` everywhere as I've read that's leads to "scope soup". [Here is an attempt](http://plnkr.co/edit/gs0s1FeIu3B2DsEMBkzp?p=preview) at trying to save the value

Comment: +1 for trying to be conscious of good habits, but I wouldn't worry about that at this level. The prime thing to pay attention to if you're concerned about that is proper modularization and not overbloating a single resource (in this case, $scope). Understanding what's actually "soup" comes from knowing what's available, and what different components are actually meant for, which are concepts above just AngularJS.